# How to color lines with specific colors in Vega-Lite?

Tags: vega-lite

VegaLite assigns colors automatically. The Gold prices are Blue, and Silver prices are Orange, which feels wrong.

[image]

**How can I assign explicit colours** - `#F1C40F` for Gold and `#95A5A6` for Silver?

I also would like to keep the `data.values` as in the example code below - as a set of separate arrays.

Code and [Playground](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Stock prices of 5 Tech Companies over Time.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "dates": ["2000-01", "2000-02", "2000-03"], 
        "gold": [1, 2, 1], 
        "silver": [1.5, 1, 2]
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"flatten": ["dates", "gold", "silver"]},
    {"fold": ["gold", "silver"], "as": ["symbol", "price"]},
    {"calculate": "datetime(datum.dates)", "as": "dates"}
  ],
  "mark": {"type": "line", "point": {"filled": false, "fill": "white"}},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "dates", "type": "temporal", "timeUnit": "yearmonth"},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "symbol", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set a custom [Color Scheme](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#scheme) using the `scale.domain` and `scale.range` arguments:

```
"color": {
  "field": "symbol",
  "type": "nominal",
  "scale": {"domain": ["gold", "silver"], "range": ["#F1C40F", "#95A5A6"]}
}
```

This works regardless of how the data source is specified.

Here is the result when applied to your chart ([Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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)):

[image]